# will_paginate "breaks" query result

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

I have a query which shows 3566 results what is ok.
When I use paginate on it, result is 18 but in console I see that query which it runs is ok

this is my controller

```
  def listcontractors
@listcons = Contract.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 50).joins(:contractor)


    .select("contractors.id,name,ico,city,country,count(resultinfo_id)")
              .group("contractors.id,name,ico,city,country")
              .order("name")
  end
```

this is query I see in console, when I put it in psql result is ok

> (22.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all,
>   contractors.id,name,ico,city,country AS
>   contractors_id_name_ico_city_country FROM "contractors" INNER JOIN
>   "contracts" ON "contracts"."contractor_id" = "contractors"."id" GROUP
>   BY contractors.id,name,ico,city,country   Contractor Load (30.8ms) 
>   SELECT  contractors.id,name,ico,city,country,count(resultinfo_id) as
>   count FROM "contractors" INNER JOIN "contracts" ON
>   "contracts"."contractor_id" = "contractors"."id" GROUP BY
>   contractors.id,name,ico,city,country  ORDER BY name LIMIT 50 OFFSET
>   1050

when I remove .paginate part from the query, result is ok
my models are

```
    class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resultinfo
  belongs_to :contractor
end

class Contractor < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :contracts
end
```

I tried to switch query to Contractor.joins(:contract) but issue was same, with paginate result is much lower than it should be

any idea why this happens?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

thanks to gmcnaughton I created this solution

```
ids = Contractor.order("name").pluck(:id)
 @listcons = ids.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 50)
 @groupedcons = Contractor.joins(:contracts)
     .where(id: @listcons)
     .select("contractors.id,name,ico,city,country,count(resultinfo_id)")
     .group("contractors.id,name,ico,city,country")
     .order("name")
```

and I had to add to initializers require 'will_paginate/array' because otherwise it shows undefined total_pages method for an array

Answer (score 0):

Mixing `paginate` and `group` is tricky. `paginate` sets an OFFSET and LIMIT on the query, which get applied to the result of the GROUP BY -- rather than limiting what records will get grouped.

If you want to paginate through the all Contracts, then group each page of 50 results (one page at a time), try this:

```
def listcontractors
  # get one page of contract ids
  ids = Contract.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 50).pluck(:id)

  # group just the items in that page
  @listcons = Contract.where(id: ids)
                      .select("contractors.id,name,ico,city,country,count(resultinfo_id)")
                      .group("contractors.id,name,ico,city,country")
                      .order("name")
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: when I tried this, I see in console that query is running my group on 50ids, but I get an error undefined method `total_pages' for #<Contract::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f29806a5490>

Comment: In that case you might need to switch it up: `@listcons = Contract.paginate...`, and `@groupedcons = Contract.where(id: ids)...`  Then in your view, display the items from `@groupedcons.each` (the grouped list) but call `will_paginate @listcons` (the paginated list).

Comment: thanks I had to do it little different but it works finally